# How to adjust a code if there is more than one minimum value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a code that will look at the city a call takes place in and then assigns a team in a city to remedy the call. There are 7 team locations and the teams are assigned by which team has the lightest workload. If two teams have the same workload it is assigned to the team in the nearest city.

I'm having problems thinking about how a loop would calculate the minimum workload but then also take into account there being more than one min and then decide to use the nearest location of minimums.

right now I have a sheet that has the date of the call and the number of days to completion for each call. I have an array (N4:N10) that displays the last completion date for each team location. Right now my loop is just taking the minimum of those completion dates and assigning the corresponding team to the call and then incrementing the last completion date by the expected number of days to complete the last call, but it's not taking into account there being more than one minimum.

```
Sub TeamAssignment()
   Dim lastRow As Integer
   Dim i As Integer
   lastRow = Worksheets("Calc").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Dim SmallestWorkload As Date
   Dim TeamAssigned As String

   For i = 3 To lastRow
      'find smallest workload and put into sheet
      SmallestWorkload = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Sheets("Calc").Range("N4:N10"))
      TeamAssigned = SmallestWorkload.Offset(0, 1).Value
      Range(i, "F").Value = TeamAssigned

      If TeamAssigned = "Miami" Then
         MIAcompletion = SmallestWorkload + Range(i, "I").Value
         Range("N9").Value = MIAcompletion
      ElseIf TeamAssigned = "Jacksonville" Then
         JAXcompletion = SmallestWorkload + Range(i, "I").Value
         Range("N5").Value = JAXcompletion
      ElseIf TeamAssigned = "New Smyrna Beach" Then
         NSBcompletion = SmallestWorkload + Range(i, "I").Value
         Range("N6").Value = NSBcomplation
      ElseIf TeamAssigned = "Ocala" Then
         OCALAcompletion = SmallestWorkload + Range(i, "I").Value
         Range("N7").Value = OCALAcompletion
      ElseIf TeamAssigned = "St. Petersburg" Then
         SPcompletion = SmallestWorkload + Range(i, "I").Value
         Range("N8").Value = SPcompletion
      ElseIf TeamAssigned = "Gainesville" Then
         GNVcompletion = SmallestWorkload + Range(i, "I").Value
         Range("N4").Value = GNVcompletion
      Else
         PSLcompletion = SmallestWorkload + Range(i, "I").Value
         Range("N10").Value = PSLcompletion
      End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Your bigger problem is determining distance? Even after you determine all possible minimums, you still need to assign via distance from there.

Comment: I cannot see how this code even compiles.  `SmallestWorkload` is a `Date` variable, and then `TeamAssigned` is being set to to the value of `SmallestWorklaod.Offset(0,1).Value` which could only happen if `SmallestWorkload` was of type `Range`.  I'm going to take a wild stab at a solution in a second, but I think you might get more people helping if you could add a picture of the data.

Comment: GD Lauren, your code does not describe how you determine the 'nearest city' or where it decides that the workload between teams are equal. All your code does now is determine the oldest date (i.e. minimum in the range(N4:N10) -this is not an array by the way- and then decides to update the value in column "F" of a table which, apparently, holds some data after which It updates the finishing date of the last found team and then loops. There are a couple of things wrong with it, but let's start at the beginning (typo at NSBcomplAtion) what data is in your table (column A through I) ?

Comment: distance calculations are in another sheet, that's completely done and not a problem at all. There's 7 tabs of data I'm using but my current issue is just how to go about this loop. Demetri, this was a rough outline code. I'm aware that doesn't work. I'm more concerned about logic at the moment.

Comment: So essentially what is happening is that a city is inputted. I have a distance matrix with long/lat coordinates to determine distance.I also have a column for expected days to completion based on a equation. From that I am looking at the date and location of a call and assigning a team based on which one has the lightest workload. I'm determining lightest workload based based on which team will be done with their current scheduled jobs the fastest (the min of the dates) but the issue is that there are instanced when that min value will be for more than one team and I need to find -

Comment: a way to tell the code that when this occurs (more than one minimum)  I need it to decide the city has the nearest location. The code here doesn't run, it is a rough outline. My issue is logic of how to go about indicating if there id more than one value for the minimum. Something like " If more than one min, then nearest city"

Comment: Sorry about responding so late, I left after posting the answer and just got in.  I was wondering if the general idea in my solution was helpful or if something further was needed.  If so please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The below is an example of how one might try to look at two conditions in a loop using vba code.

You will have to then assign the variables at the end to the cells you wish them to go in, and add code to update the final team that was chosen, but perhaps it gives you some ideas.

```
Sub TeamAssignment()

    ' Assuming column N has the workload date, column O has the Team, and column P has the distance in miles
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    lastRow = Worksheets("Calc").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim TeamAssigned As String, SmallestWorkload As Date, ClosestTeam As Double

    ' Choose the first team to begin with
    SmallestWorkload = Range("N3").Value: TeamAssigned = Range("O3").Value: ClosestTeam = Range("P3").Value

    'find smallest workload and put into sheet
    For i = 3 To lastRow
        Select Case Range("N" & i).Value
            Case Is < SmallestWorkload
                ' If we find a smaller workload, then assign it to this team
                SmallestWorkload = Range("N" & i).Value: TeamAssigned = Range("O" & i).Value: ClosestTeam = Range("P" & i).Value
            Case Is = SmallestWorkload
                ' If the workload is the same, then determine if it should be assigned based on the distance
                If Range("P" & i).Value < ClosestTeam Then _
                    SmallestWorkload = Range("N" & i).Value: TeamAssigned = Range("O" & i).Value: ClosestTeam = Range("P" & i).Value
        End Select
    Next i


End Sub
```